# How to stop Wordpress from redirecting subdomain to the main domain?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

Searched stackoverflow for an answer to this one, but couldn't find any that works.

My problem is: I have a site called http://lasalida.net (for the Madrid location), and I copied it to a subdomain to set up a site for the Zaragoza location: http://zaragoza.lasalida.net

I have set site_url and home in database, both are set for the subdomain. 
No redirects in .htaccess , tried it even without htaccess, same happens.

If I use the subdomains base link, it redirects to main domain

If I use any of the pages under the subdomain, I stay at the subdomain.

Only the first page, the main page gets redirected to the main domain address.

What should I do to get the base address of the subdomain to work, without redirection?

Comment: Did you update your permalinks?

Comment: Yes, the permalink, of the page that is set as main, also points to the subdomain.

Comment: Please show us your .htaccess file contents

Comment: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

But it doesn't matters, same happens if I delete the .htaccess file.

Comment: You should have two .htaccess files. One for your main (madrid location) site and one in the subdirectory for your subdomain site (Zaragoza location).

Comment: Because they are copied, they are the same :)

Comment: Try adding this to your subdomain .htaccess file: RewriteOptions inherit

Comment: Tried, nothing, same thing happening

Answer (score 1):

I have the same URL setup - subdomain on my main domain - and was having the same issue.

I have .htaccess files in both directories. They were the same but I changed the .htaccess in the Subdomain directory to the code below based on the .htaccess "Subdomain Example" on the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) page and now the dev site on the subdomain works fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is, is add the following to your wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://subdomain.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://subdomain.example.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution (based on skapie19s answer above):

```php
// Generate home-URL based on the current request.
$home_proto = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https';
$home_url   = $home_proto . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

// Assign the dynamic home-URL to the WordPress config.
define( 'WP_HOME',$home_url );
define( 'WP_SITEURL',$home_url );
```

This small snippet allows you to use multiple domains for your WordPress website. For example, you have assigned the following URLs to your website:

- lasalida.net
- zaragoza.lasalida.net
- subdomain.lasalida.net

All of those domains will display the same website without redirecting to a single "primary" domain.

### Variation: Remove "www"

Here's a second sample that allows multiple (sub)domains for the same website, but will redirect the "www." subdomain to the top domain:

```php
// Prepare the Domain: "www.domain.com" will be changed to "domain.com".
$home_domain = str_replace( 'www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
$home_proto  = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https';
$home_url    = $home_proto . '://' . $home_domain;

// Assign the dynamic home-URL to the WordPress config.
define( 'WP_HOME',$home_url );
define( 'WP_SITEURL',$home_url );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a .htaccess file with this content to your subdomain directory base:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```